# Java Matcher: How to match multiple lines with one regex

Tags: java, regex

My method takes a file, and tries to extract the text between the header `###Title###` and closing `###---###`. I need it to extract multiple lines and put each line into an array. But since `readAllLines()` converts all lines into an array, I don't know how to compare and match it.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getData(File f, String title) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> input = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    //String? readLines = somehow make it possible to match
    System.out.println("Checking entry.");

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("###" + title + "###(.*)###---###", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(readLines);
    if (m.matches()) {
        m.matches();
        String matched = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("Contents: " + matched);
        String[] array = matched.split("\n");
        ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String j:array) {
            array2.add(j);
        }
        output = array2;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No matches.");
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here is my file, and I'm 100% sure that the compiler is reading the correct one.

```
###Test File###
Entry 1
Entry 2
Data 1
Data 2
Test 1
Test 2
###---###
```

The output says *"No matches."* instead of the entries.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Will all these be in a single line or as it is in pic?

Comment: @PM77-1 How do I make it so it matches instead of returning a "No matches." method?

Comment: @Octopus Multiple lines. Exactly as posted.

Comment: Are you actually reading in all of the lines?

Comment: Have you tried `join`ing the lines?

Comment: You read the file into an ArrayList `input` but match onto a variable `readLines`? Either the first is superfluous or the second probably empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. It's enough to loop through the array and compare items line by line, taking those between the start and end tags.

```
ArrayList<String> input = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

boolean matched = false;
for (String line : input) {
    if (line.equals("###---###") && matched) matched = false; //needed parentheses
    if (matched) output.add(line);
    if (line.equals("###Test File###") && !matched) matched = true;
}
```

Comment: Now, i can understand it. when header is matched, adding the next line. when the footer is matched, you are making matched as false. This will add only the lines in between them. cool :) I have rep +1

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, if they are going to be in the same way as posted, then i don't think `regex` is needed for this requirement. You can read line by line and do a contains of '###'

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {
  ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Get the object of DataInputStream
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // this line will skip the header and footer with '###'
  if(!strLine.contains("###");
   dataList.add(strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
//Now dataList has all the data between ###Test File### and ###---###
}
```

You can also change the *contains* method *parameter* according to your requirement to ignore lines!

Comment: This will also match lines before the start tag and after the end tag.

Comment: Maybe. But the text of the question suggested a broader usage.

Comment: Why are you using a `DataInputStream`?  You can construct the `InputStreamReader` directly from the `FileInputStream`; the `DataInputStream` adds nothing of value.